# How do I restrict a public function to be accessed by a class/namespace only?

Tags: php, class, namespaces

While developing a small database wrapper for my project I wanted to give restricted access to a function.
This restriction should prevent plugins - residing in a different namespace, but able to access this wrapper by design - from executing that function.

How is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question here. If you have other suggestions, feel free to improve!

While directly restricting access in this form by PHPs internals is not possible. It is possible for the function to 'protect' itself.
This is done by exploiting `\debug_backtrace()` to gain information about the caller and evaluating its namespace(s) and/or class.

One example:

```
/**
 * Will return true if called from within 'Namespace\Class', false otherwhise.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function test() {
    // Get debug_backtrace. This function will be at index 0.
    $backtrace = \debug_backtrace();
    // If the caller is a function it will be at index 1, if not, it will not exist
    // and we will not execute the indented code.
    if (false === \array_key_exists(1, $backtrace)
        // If the caller is within a class the 'class' key will exist
        || false === \array_key_exists('class', $backtrace[1])
        // and its name including namespace(s) will be the string-value of this key.
        // If it does not exist nor start with 'Namespace\Class' this block will trigger.
        || 0 !== \strpos($backtrace[1]['class'], 'Namespace\Class')
    ) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: this is a sloppy solution, because on different systems `debug_backtrace` may give different results. For instance, I develop on Debian, but my production server is on FreeBSD. On both those systems `debug_backtrace` had different output, causing something like you have here to work on Debian, but to ultimately fail and return false every time it was run on FreeBSD.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out.  Although i think it should not be different on different platforms, the fact that it can happen is necessary to point out.    Thanks!